# Sqlite return mobile number without 0

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having SQLite DB table with four fields. I am entering mobile number starting with 0 (For example: 09987654321). I have stored mobile number as String value. When I am trying to retrieve the value it returns without 0 (Like 9987654321).

I have used a DBHelper class.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Application_Status (Applicant_Name TEXT NOT NULL,DateOfBirth TEXT NOT NULL,MobileNumber TEXT NOT NULL,Status TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT Pending,App_ID TEXT);
```

Insert :

```
public long insert(String tablename, String[] column, String[] values) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
        cv.put(column[i], values[i]);
    }
    return db.insert(tablename, null, cv);
}
```

For retriving:

```
public Cursor Search(String tablename, String[] columns, String selectarg,
        String[] selectvalues, String groupby, String having, String orderby) {
    Cursor c = db.query(tablename, columns, selectarg, selectvalues,
            groupby, having, orderby);
    return c;
}
```

I have retrieved the String as,

```
DatabaseUtil dba=new DatabaseUtil(context);
Cursor cursor=dba.Search(DatabaseUtil.TABLE_STATUS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
if(cursor.getCount>0)
{
c.moveToFirst();
String mob=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseUtil.APPST_Mobileno));
...
}
```

'APPST_Mobileno' -is the tablename refernce in DatabaseUtil class.

I have checked the table and the value is correctly inserted with 0. Why it not returning without 0 while retrieving?

I have updated my code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is `Mobileno` column of `LONG` type?

Comment: No.. I declared it as a TEXT type

Comment: post your schema of table here

Comment: Even though you say the value is correctly inserted, post your insertion code, too.

Comment: How you verified insertion is correct ?

Comment: I have pulled the Sqlite db and checked using Sqlite browser.

Comment: I am getting the values from 'EditText' as String and passed as string object. public long insert() method sets the same object type as i have passed. I haven't converted to integers. then how it will be assigned as Numeric strings?

Comment: Ok, have you debug your code and checked what you are receiving in `mob` ?

Comment: Only on debugging my code I have found that i am getting only 10digits without 0. I have checked both in mobile and emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever number is returned can be left padded with zeroes:

```
String mob=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Mobileno"));
mob = String.format("%011d", Integer.parseInt(mob));
```